# "Buongiorno" versus "buon giorno": qual è la forma più usata?

Tags: difference, orthography

L'altro giorno volevo redigere un messaggio di posta elettronica in italiano. Stavo per cominciare scrivendo "Buongiorno" quando ho avuto il dubbio se si potesse usare la forma staccata, "Buon giorno". Ho cercato ["buongiorno" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/buongiorno1/) e, per aumentare la mia confusione, ecco quello che ho trovato:

> **buongiórno** (o **bongiórno**; più com. **buòn giórno**) locuz. e s. m. – Formula di saluto e d’augurio che [...]

Significa questo che la forma "buon giorno" è (o era)  la più comune?

Comment: Se dovessi indicare il saluto in un discorso diretto scriverei *Buon giorno*; il nome del saluto è *buongiorno* (come in *dare il buongiorno*).

Comment: @egreg: E il discorso diretto comprende testi come una lettera o un messaggio di posta elettronica?

Comment: Non auguro mai “Buon giorno” in una email. `;-)`

Comment: Io uso *Buongiorno* tutto attaccato, ma è vero che non è una parola che si vede molto spesso scritta.

Comment: Il sito che ho citato contiene delle inesattezze ,  provvedo subito a cancellare la mia risposta. Scusa.

Comment: Potrebbe interessarle questo pezzo su "buondì vs buon dì", sul sito ell'Accademia della Crusca: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/augurandoci-buond

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sono entrambe corrette. A quanto pare da [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Buongiorno%2C%20buon%20giorno&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2160&corpus=22&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2CBuongiorno%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBuongiorno%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbuongiorno%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBUONGIORNO%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbuon%20giorno%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBuon%20giorno%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbuon%20giorno%3B%2Cc0) la forma più usata a partire dagli anni 50 (almeno nella letteratura) è diventata **buongiorno**.

Come spiega il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_669.html), l'unico caso in cui è da utlizzare esclusivamente la forma [univerbata](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univerbazione) è quando **buongiorno** si usa come sostantivo:

> Dare il **buongiorno**